# Need a redistributable edition of Free AVG

Tags: portable, internet-connection, avg-antivirus

So, I'm trying to install AVG on someone else's computer (with permission, I promise!) but their internet connection is spotty. The d/l is stopped and sent back to square one when the line goes down, so I need to download it from a good terminal, and then shove it on a flash drive or something and give it to them.

Does anyone know of a place where I can download the full program--not just the installer?

Comment: Just a word of advice... AVG has been responsible for deleting critical windows system files and [breaking windows](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbo=1&rlz=1C1GPCK_enUS395&tbs=qdr:y&q=avg+breaking+windows&aq=f&aqi=g4g-sv1&aql=&oq=) in other ways on numerous occasions lately. You might want to consider installing a different A/V product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://free.avg.com/gb-en/download.prd-afg

Will give you an 84 MB installer for the free version of AVG

Edit:

As mentioned by Greg there is another link which will give you all current versions (including Linux) at http://free.avg.com/gb-en/download-free-all-product

**UPDATE: 2017/01/09**

[Thanks to user570976 below](https://superuser.com/a/1165141/74026) we learn that these links no longer work, and currently the only way to download AVG is using their downloader program.

Comment: \o/ That's just huge.. oO (Maybe they want to compete with NVidia installer? :-D)

Comment: It probably has support for WinXP through to 7, hence the size.  I remember a time when downloading that would have tied up a modem for 8 hours, all the while praying that your connection would hold, now it's a minute or two...

Comment: ...and someone would always pick up the phone at 83.9 MB.

Comment: They seem to have moved it to here now: http://free.avg.com/gb-en/download-free-all-product

Comment: @Greg Thanks for the link, I've added it into my answer in order to keep it current and valid.  My original link was also (kind-of) valid but set a tab within the page to "Documentation" so I've corrected that too.

Answer (score 1):

As of January 2017, it appears that AVG has deliberately removed all of the URL's, including the two in the previous answer to this question, that used to allow download of the redistributables. After an exhaustive search of the AVG website - which has been completely redesigned from what it was a year or two ago - I can no longer find any references whatsoever to redistributables for either the main program or the virus definition files. All Web links for AVG Free now just take you to the 3.2 mB "installer". What are people are supposed to do when they only have dial-up or a "spotty" internet connection? No way am I going to d/l 150+ megabytes on dial-up.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I'll add this information to the accepted answer so that future viewers will see it.

Answer (score 0):

AVG has rebranded their products. AVG antivirus is now installed through a program called AVG Protection Free; however, there are still standalone installers for just the antivirus solution.

Once downloaded, beware that the software will still need to download the latest virus definition database and possibly update itself. So while the bulk is offline, it is not truly a completely offline resource. To avoid that, AVG offers the latest virus definition database for [download here](http://www.avg.com/ww-en/download-update) (114MB as of January 9, 2017).

[32-bit direct download](http://files-download.avg.com/inst/mp/AVG_Antivirus_Free_x86_694.exe) (230MB)

[64-bit direct download](http://files-download.avg.com/inst/mp/AVG_Antivirus_Free_x64_693.exe) (253MB)

To remove AVG entirely, they offer [a removal tool](http://files-download.avg.com/util/tools/AVG_Remover.exe) (~8MB).